# How to calculate Scrabble Score of a word

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program to calculate the score of a word, based on the game Scrabble[image]

The scores are based off the image above.

I've currently coded a function, my ideal goal is to use this and get the user to input a word to calculate the score.

```
int scrabbleScore(String Word) {
        int score = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Word.length(); i++){
            char calculatedLetter = Word.at(i);
            switch (calculatedLetter) {
                case 'A':
                case 'E':
                case 'I':
                case 'L':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                case 'R':
                case 'S':
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                    score +=1; break;
                case 'D':
                case 'G':
                    score +=2; break;
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                case 'M':
                case 'P':
                    score +=3; break;
                case 'F':
                case 'H':
                case 'V':
                case 'W':
                case 'Y':
                    score +=4; break;
                case 'K':
                    score +=5; break;
                case 'J':
                case 'X':
                    score +=8; break;
                case 'Q':
                case 'Z':
                    score +=10; break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
        return score;
```

Why is this giving me a score of 0 for any word?

Comment: You seem to have a function in-place, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Even if you won't hit in this case the limit, I like to inform people when I see such big switch cases, that it produces undefined behavior if you have a switch with more then 1023 containing cases.

Comment: It's giving me an error Too few arguments in function call

Comment: Were we supposed to *guess* that? Are we now supposed to guess which line that error occurs on? Should we also guess how many arguments are *supposed* to be there? Today's your lucky day: You'll learn a bit about programming, *and* you'll pick up some basic question-asking skills. The later will help you in life more than the former.

Comment: I managed to solve that was a stupid miss type, but its not calculating the score.

Comment: You check for uppercase letters only.

Comment: Without making any changes to the code, you've changed the problem from one of compilation to one of run-time behavior. Those are entirely different classes of problems, and if you didn't change the code, then it's a major clue that the code shown here is not the (sole) source of the problem. Please show enough code to reproduce the problem. Furthermore, what word did you type in to test with, and what result did you expect from it?

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a bit shorter and prepare for one day multi-language with few modifications.

```
int scrabbleScore(string Word)
{
    int score = 0;
    char EnglishScoreTable[26] = { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };
    for (auto Letter : Word)
    {
        if (Letter >= 'A' && Letter <= 'Z')
        {
            score += EnglishScoreTable[Letter - 'A'];
        }
        else
        {
            // error in input 
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: Seems nice and a lot neater. Let say the word has a '-' in the word, how can I make this word not return any score?

Comment: This is a nice compact solution for English ASCII. But how does this prepare for multilanguage? If anything it appears to prevent it from other languages as there is an implicit assumption all characters in the alphabet reside contiguously in the ordinal space. But many languages have accents etc that prevent the use of an array index as you've done here.

Comment: @hayde you could treat special character in the else case.

Comment: @pp yes it's not perfectly multi language but the idea of table lookup. It could be change at runtime and is adaptable to any language the table will be 256bytes in ANSI and 64kb in unicode. If moving above 26 characters I would prefer creating the lookup table from scrabble score at runtime.

Comment: I think you've neglected to answer the question. Remember this is Stack Overflow; Code Review is a separate site.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string word;
std::cin>>word;
std::cout<<"Your Score :" << scrabbleScore(word) ;
```

Also,

```
int scrabbleScore(String Word)
                  ^ this should be string from std namespace,
```

Comment: How do you know what type the argument should have? Have you read the assignment?

Comment: @RobKennedy Now you'll say OP can have a `class`  named `String` ?

Comment: Of course. It's my impression that custom string classes are pretty common in introductory programming classes.

Comment: My function seems to not be calculating the score, it just prints 0 for every word.

Comment: @Hayde that's probably because you need to check for lowercase too

Answer (score 0):

Change imp to this:

```
private static int scrabbleScore(String Word) {
    int score = 0;
    String upperWord = Word.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < upperWord.length(); i++){
        char calculatedLetter = upperWord.charAt(i);
        switch (calculatedLetter) {
```

Comment: What do you mean by "imp"?

Comment: Implementation.  Apols for the ambiguous abbrev.  :-)

Comment: +1 for addressing a problem described in the question, but -1 for implicitly suggesting that the project be re-implemented in an *entirely different language*.

Comment: True!   I was on autopilot and just selected all and pasted it into emacs and ran javac.  The obvious syntax clues like std::cout << "message" were not there and I didn't see the other example till later.   Completely didn't think about C++ at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const score = (test) => {
    test = test.toUpperCase()
    var s = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'].some(function (v) { return test[i].indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
            s += 1
        }
        if (['D', 'G'].some(function (v) { return test[i].indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
            s += 2
        }
        if (['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'].some(function (v) { return test[i].indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
            s += 4
        }
        if (['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'].some(function (v) { return test[i].indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
            s += 3
        }
        if (['K'].some(function (v) { return test[i].indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
            s += 5
        }
        if (['J', 'X'].some(function (v) { return test[i].indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
            s += 8
        }
        if (['Q', 'Z'].some(function (v) { return test[i].indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
            s += 10
        }
    }
    return s
};
```